# BigQuery Sink Connector - Table name in BigQuery

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

In Google BigQuery Sink Connector, if autoCreateTables property is true, then GCP creates BigQuery table in the name of topics field. If autoCreateTables is given false, then we should manually create table in GCP with topic name as table name. What if we want different table name other than topic name?

https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-bigquery/current/kafka_connect_bigquery_config.html

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the `RegexRouter` transform, for example to rename the topic before it reaches the sink.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html

Comment: Thanks!. But one of the limitation of Google BigQuery Sink connector is it does not support few SMTs and RegexRouter is one of it!.                                                                                             <https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-bigquery/current/overview.html>

Comment: Only if the two properties mentioned are enabled. And that's only because it uses the topic name to perform upsert/delete actions. If you've enabled them, then, no, it's not possible to have a different table than the topic